# Spring and JMS. Separate queue for every client application. Is it right approach?

Tags: spring, architecture, activemq-classic, message-queue

I need to design fault tolerance processing of client requests. Every request is passed to several systems consequently with separate messages. And even one of systems isn't working right now request must be process to the point of sending to this system and at this point it must wait for recovering system for about one day. After one day of system unavailability request goes to special manual process. Special application is responsible for messages routing. Also this application is only message broker producer and consumer. Message broker is used for persistence of messages and for redelivery policy.

My idea is that every client request process should use its own queue in message broker. So doesn't matter that happens to particular request - other requests are processed separately. And I faced the problem with dynamic servicing of message listeners. As I use Spring I need to dynamically create `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` as spring bean. I can deal with this. But the next problem is that I need to destroy `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` with listener in it when the particular client request is fully done and queue in message broker is empty. I don't have any notification at the time when request is done or queue was automatically destroyed in message broker because of inactivity for some time. I see only one way - to create special task that will poll message broker for active queues and destroy `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` if its destination was deleted.

I think it is logically right as I need queue for processing client request but I don't need queue of client requests. But this solution is too complicated. The simple solution with queue per concrete system seems logically wrong. But it's easy.

Could someone give me advice with this situation? I think I'm wrong somewhere, but I can't understand exact point where I'm wrong.

My technologies are: Java, Spring, ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use RabbitMQ or something like that? If so, you could create a queue for each of your systems to queue client requests there. If some problem occures to your system, its queue will just grow accumulating all requests. When service resumes it's work, it will continue to pop messages off the queue and process them.

To put requests to manual processing, you can create a separate process, that will peek into each queue and check the date of messages without deleting them from queue. If they are outdated, it should pop them off the queue and transfer, may be, to `manual-processing` queue or whatever it is.

Comment: My problem isn't in choosing the right message broker. It's more about architecture. I already implement this functionality, but it still seems to complicated for this quite usual needs.
But anyway thank you for wish to help!